# Generating a list of reference in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm really not sure how to explain thats why im having hard time googling a solution.

So I added this in my doxyfile
ALIASES += "sprint=\xrefitem sprint \"Sprint\" \"Sprint\" "

I was able to see this 
[image]

This is fine but I want something different, kind of reverse of this. I want to be able to see one Sprint which is 19 and it should be a link so when I want to see all codes that are related to sprint 19 I will be able to just click on 19 and see the list of objects related to it. If I do it this way it will be really hard to find the codes on a specific sprint when we reach sprint 100++ or something.

So instead of seeing this
-Department
--19
-Employee
--19
-Position
--19

I should see
-19
--Department
--Employee
--Position

Hope I made sense.. :)